# Randomize function repetative / predicable

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have this procedure that runs on FormActivate, it utilizes the randomize procedure, but is giving repetitive results. I use the variable OutText to show the results, and they return extremely repetative / predictable numbers (eg. 444555666  !  444555666).

```
procedure TMainWin.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
  var
    i, i2, TileValue : integer;
    OutText : String;
begin

  MainWin.Width := SCALE * WIDTH;
  MainWin.Height := SCALE * HEIGHT;

  OutText := '';

  for i := 1 to 5 do begin

    Randomize;
    TileValue := Random(20) + 1;
    arTilesFinal[i, TileValue] := 1;

    for i2 := 1 to 2 do begin
      While arTilesFinal[i, TileValue] > 0 do begin
        Randomize;
        TileValue := Random(20) + 1;
      end;
      arTilesFinal[i, TileValue] := 2;
    end;

    for i2 := 1 to 2 do begin;
      While arTilesFinal[i, TileValue] > 0 do begin
        Randomize;
        TileValue := Random(20) + 1;
      end;
      arTilesFinal[i, TileValue] := 3;
    end;

    for i2 := 1 to 5 do begin;
      While arTilesFinal[i, TileValue] > 0 do begin
        Randomize;
        TileValue := Random(20) + 1;
      end;
      arTilesFinal[i, TileValue] := 4;
    end;

    for i2 := 1 to 5 do begin;
      While arTilesFinal[i, TileValue] > 0 do begin
        Randomize;
        TileValue := Random(20) + 1;
      end;
      arTilesFinal[i, TileValue] := 5;
    end;

    for i2 := 1 to 5 do begin;
      While arTilesFinal[i, TileValue] > 0 do begin
        Randomize;
        TileValue := Random(20) + 1;
      end;
      arTilesFinal[i, TileValue] := 6;
    end;
  end;

  for i := 1 to 5 do begin
    for i2 := 1 to 20 do begin
      OutText := OutText + IntToStr(arTilesFinal[i,i2]) + ',';
    end;
    OutText := OutText + '  !  ';
  end;

  ShowMessage(OutText);
  //AddImages;
end;
```

aTiles and aTilesFinal are defined as follows

```
type
  aTiles = array[1..20] of integer;
  aTilesFinal = array[1..5] of aTiles;

var
  arTilesFinal : aTilesFinal;
```

Answer (score 2):

You may not call randomize in a loop for each call to 'random'.
Call randomize once, then do all the random function calls.

Comment: I removed all randomize calls except for the very first and it now gives much better results. Thank you

Comment: @AlphaMc111: Move the one and only remaining call to `Randomize` to your form's `OnCreate` handler instead. It should be called only once ever during your app's run; placing it in `OnActivate` will call it every time your form gains focus, which can result in multiple calls.

Comment: The best ever place for `randomize` is inside the `.dpr` file